# Function to find point of intersection between a ray and a sphere? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, 3d, raycasting

I was going to stop at intervals on the ray and check if they were within the radius of the sphere. I found much more efficient mathematical ways to do this but they are all written in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (inefficient version but without any dependency and easy to follow):

```
function dotProduct(v1, v2) {
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y + v1.z * v2.z;
}

function squaredLength(v) {
    return dotProduct(v, v);
}

// Returns whether the ray intersects the sphere
// @param[in] center center point of the sphere (C)
// @param[in] radius radius of the sphere (R)
// @param[in] origin origin point of the ray (O)
// @param[in] direction direction vector of the ray (D)
// @param[out] intersection closest intersection point of the ray with the sphere, if any
function intersectRayWithSphere(center, radius,
                                origin, direction,
                                intersection) {
    // Solve |O + t D - C|^2 = R^2
    //       t^2 |D|^2 + 2 t < D, O - C > + |O - C|^2 - R^2 = 0
    var OC = intersection; // Use the output parameter as temporary workspace

    OC.x = origin.x - center.x;
    OC.y = origin.y - center.y;
    OC.z = origin.z - center.z;

    // Solve the quadratic equation a t^2 + 2 t b + c = 0
    var a = squaredLength(direction);
    var b = dotProduct(direction, OC);
    var c = squaredLength(OC) - radius * radius;
    var delta = b * b - a * c;

    if (delta < 0) // No solution
        return false;

    // One or two solutions, take the closest (positive) intersection
    var sqrtDelta = Math.sqrt(delta);

    // a >= 0
    var tMin = (-b - sqrtDelta) / a;
    var tMax = (-b + sqrtDelta) / a;

    if (tMax < 0) // All intersection points are behind the origin of the ray
        return false;

    // tMax >= 0
    var t = tMin >= 0 ? tMin : tMax;

    intersection.x = origin.x + t * direction.x;
    intersection.y = origin.y + t * direction.y;
    intersection.z = origin.z + t * direction.z;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not super used to this stuff. How are things expressed?
Are they all arrays?

Comment: The points and vectors are objects expected to have x, y, z properties. For instance: `var intersection = {x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0};`

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if I'm wrong, intersectRayWithSphere({x:0,y:0,z:0},3,{x:-5,y:0,z:0},{x:1,y:0,z:0}).intersection

Comment: Why, if the function aims to find the point of intersection, is intersection itself a parameter of the function?

Comment: In the proposed code, intersection is an output parameter. This avoids having the function create a small vector on each call and allows the same vector object to be instead reused.